# Bootstrap file upload not working with ASP Ajax AsyncFileUpload

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, asp.net-ajax, asyncfileupload

So I am having an issue on my ASP web form, where I am using Bootstrap and trying to make use of the Ajax AsyncFileUpload control. The file upload control looks like this:

```
<div id="LoafFileUploadTemplate" class="custom-file">
    <asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="LoafFileUpload" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="custom-file-input file-upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" OnClientUploadStarted="Loaf_UploadStarted" OnClientUploadComplete="Loaf_UploadComplete" OnUploadedComplete="LoafFileUpload_UploadedComplete" />
    <label class="custom-file-label">Choose File</label>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="LoafFileUploadComplete" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="d-none" OnClick="LoafFileUploadComplete_Click" />
```

For some reason the LoafFileUpload_UploadedComplete method didn't fire when the uploader was finished. I've read that I need to add ***enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"*** to the file input. I have done that, but still doesn't work. Turns out the way bootstrap renders the AsyncFileUpload control, these two attributes get applied to a div instead of the file upload control, as seen below:

```
<div id="LoafFileUploadTemplate" class="custom-file">
<div id="LoafFileUpload" class="custom-file-input file-upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="ctl00$CPH_main$CsatoltFajlok$LoafFileUpload$ctl00"><div><input name="ctl00$CPH_main$CsatoltFajlok$LoafFileUpload$ctl02" type="file" id="ctl00_CPH_main_CsatoltFajlok_LoafFileUpload_ctl02" style="" size="20"></div>
</div>
<label class="custom-file-label">Fájl feltöltése</label>
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$CPH_main$CsatoltFajlok$LoafFileUploadComplete" value="" id="LoafFileUploadComplete" class="d-none">
```

So as seen here, the ***enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"*** attributes are applied onto the div containing the file input, not the input itself. Because of this, the file doesn't get posted to the server. Anyones know a fix for this?

Comment: It not clear why having bootstrap or not would make a difference. However, it is possbile you left out some MASSIVE detail, like say popping up a dialog with that control inside - but nothing suggests that such important information was left out in your post. I don't see anything as to why having bootstrap on the page would make a difference, but then again, if you are using say a bootstrap dialog or some such, or some active popup is being launched, then those details are beyond important here.

Comment: Well it is inside a bootstrap modal. I assume it might be a bootstrap problem, because bootstrap tends to render things differently sometimes. But I will try it with a regular file uploader without the bootstrap classes, see if it works.

What's weird is, in another page of mine, it works fine, even though it's set up pretty much the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't need to add *enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"* to the file input, but to the form itself (in my case, in the master page). It works now.